# Apply map to a list and get a list back

Tags: list, python-3.7

im using the current version of Python 3 and have a problem. I want to write a code  where the value of each element inside a list is doubled. This can easily be done by defining a double function and using map():

```
def addition(n): 
return n + n 

# We double all numbers using map() 
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = map(addition, numbers) 
print(list(result))            # line 7

error: list' object is not callable   at line 7
```

But for some reason i can't convert the map object 'result' to a list. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You must have a list variable called `list` (or `print`) defined somewhere. Check around. Don't name variables the same thing as existing built-ins.

Comment: You are right. Thx!

Comment: Also, I'll just note, there isn't much reason to use `map` in Python 3. In general, you should prefer to use list comprehensions (or generator expressions if you want laziness). They have less overhead than `map` iirc.